# avoiding unnecessary allocations for temporaries, r-value destructor

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

I have a many, MANY strings that are almost never modified after creation and access times to them is not really a concern. I have to minimize the memory usage so I opted to writing a class instead of using `std::string` which has to hold extra data such as capacity and length to conform with the standard. This change resulted in reduction of ~%30 memory usage.

To achieve this, I have written a class just wraps C-style null-terminated strings internally and manages the buffer so the class just consists of a pointer data member and it provides enough interface to rarely access and work with it like `std::string`.

I would like to avoid boilerplate code and allow transparent conversions from `std::string` and to `std::string`. So can I avoid allocating/copying the data from `std::string` on edge cases such as when temporary is needed? Consider this:

```
class A {
public:
  A(const char* p) : p_{std::strdup(p)} { }
  ~A() { free(p_); }

  A& append(const A&);

private:
  char* p_;
};
```

Now in the following code:

```
A a;
a.append("test");
```

A temporary object will be created, allocating and copying the data. Then it will be immediately destroyed. The question is, is there a way to avoid this without creating a version of every function such as `A& append(const char*)`. I would also like to support the transparent conversions for `std::string` so it will automatically become 3 versions of each function.

What effects will the following approach have:

```
class A {
public:
  A(const char* p) : p_{std::strdup(p)} { }
  A(const char* p) &&
      : p_{p} {
  }

  ~A() { free(p_); }
  ~A() && { /* nothing */ }

  A& append(const A&);

private:
  char* p_;
};
```

If this does not work, what strategy can I apply to solve this problem?

Comment: You have a big problem with UB when a copy of `A` is made.

Comment: @user2079303 This is not a full implementation, it is a small code to demonstrate my problem.

Comment: I don't see anything better than a `char*` overload. What is the issue with it ?

Comment: @Quentin I would like to support `std::string` overload, too. The issue is that when I have 15 of such operations, I have to write 45 functions to support both `char*` and `std::string`.

Comment: @Etherealone fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What effects will the following approach have:
>
> ```
> A(const char* p) &&
> ~A() &&
> ```

The most likely effect is compilation error, since standard doesn't allow ref-qualifiers on c/d-tor.

I recommend implementing `A::c_str` just like strings do, and use the following helper from a template:

```
template<class Str>
const char* c_str_help(const Str& str) {
    return str.c_str();
}
const char* c_str_help(const char* str) {
    return str;
}

class A {
  // ...

  const char* c_str() const { return p_; }

  template<class Str>
  A& append(const Str& str) {
      const char* s = c_str_help(str);
      // implement using const char* s
  }
};
```

---

PS: I recommend using a `unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)>` instead of a bare pointer for much easier implementation.

Answer (score 1):

A bit similar to [user2079303](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41617585/3233393)'s approach, with SFINAE so we don't hinder overload resolution:

```
namespace detail_A {
    char const *getString(std::string const &str) {
        return str.c_str();
    }

    char const *getString(char const *str) {
        return str;
    }

    // More `getString`s as needed...

    template <class T>
    using enableString = decltype(getString(std::declval<T>()));
}

class A {
// ...

    template <class T, class = detail_A::enableString<T>>
    A &append(T const &str) {
        char const *p = detail_A::getString(str);

        std::cout << "Appending \"" << p << "\"\n";

        return *this;
    }
};
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5b0f61b5e2da7a3)